# Copying and pasting a lot of cells using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to do a schedule. For this I need to copy a lot of ranges and fill them in other places in the same sheet. Is there a way to clean up this code to make at faster and less repetitive?

```
Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan").Range("D12:D18").Copy Range("E19:E25")
Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan").Range("D12:D18").Copy Range("F26:F32")
Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan").Range("D12:D18").Copy Range("G33:G39")
Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan").Range("D12:D18").Copy Range("H40:H46")
Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan").Range("D12:D18").Copy Range("I47:I53")
Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan").Range("D12:D18").Copy Range("J5:J11")
Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan").Range("D12:D18").Copy Range("K12:K18")
Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan").Range("D12:D18").Copy Range("L19:L25")
Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan").Range("D12:D18").Copy Range("M26:M32")
Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan").Range("D12:D18").Copy Range("N33:N39")
Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan").Range("D12:D18").Copy Range("O40:O46")
Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan").Range("D12:D18").Copy Range("P47:P53")
Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan").Range("D12:D18").Copy Range("Q12:Q18")
Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan").Range("D12:D18").Copy Range("R19:R25")
Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan").Range("D12:D18").Copy Range("S26:S32")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store all you "paste" ranges in an array, where you loop and paste per each range. See below (tested):

```
Sub CopyPasteUsingArray()

    Dim rRangeArray() As Variant
    Dim wsOU As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set wsOU = Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan")

    rRangeArray = Array("E19:E25", "F26:F32")

    wsOU.Range("D12:D18").Copy

    For i = LBound(rRangeArray) To UBound(rRangeArray)
        wsOU.Range(rRangeArray(i)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
    Next i

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can just set the values without the use of copy/ paste using a similar method.

```
Sub SetValuesArray()

    Dim rRangeArray() As Variant
    Dim wsOU As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set wsOU = Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan")

    rRangeArray = Array("E19:E25", "F26:F32")

    For i = LBound(rRangeArray) To UBound(rRangeArray)
        wsOU.Range(rRangeArray(i)).Value = wsOU.Range("D12:D18").Value
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error when i try to run the code "type mismatch" when it gets to wsOU.Range("D12:D18").Copy ?

Comment: Definitely the second option (+), and change to `Dim rRangeArray As Variant` and the code should be good to run :) @Sidvi.

Comment: Your option works perfectly when changed from string to variant. The firt option though is best suited for my needs as the cells are color coded. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another example

```
Sub copyAndPaste()

Dim i As Long
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan").Range("D12:D18")

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan")

    For i = 5 To 19
        If i < 10 Then
        myRange.Copy .Range(.Cells(19 + 7 * (i - 5), i), .Cells(19 + 6 + 7 * (i - 5), i))
        ElseIf i < 17 Then
        myRange.Copy .Range(.Cells(5 + 7 * (i - 5), i), .Cells(5 + 6 + 7 * (i - 5), i))
        Else
        myRange.Copy .Range(.Cells(12 + 7 * (i - 5), i), .Cells(12 + 6 + 7 * (i - 5), i))
        End If
    Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Looking at you code, it should work. But i does not, it pastes it the first time, then it leaves 4 blanks and then pastes again and does not start from the top again at any point???

Comment: Try now, after your comment I realized some logical mistakes by me

Comment: But You just changed the conditions of 'ifs', which in the end mean the same as my conditions :)

Comment: Yes i changed the ranges and the conditions. but other than that, your code was very good, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just do 3 loops, depending of where you start and end.

```
Dim ZZ As Long 'for rows
Dim YY As Long 'for columns

YY = 0

For ZZ = 19 To 47 Step 7
    Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan").Range("D12:D18").Copy Range(Cells(ZZ, 5 + YY), Cells(ZZ + 6, 5 + YY))
    YY = YY + 1
Next ZZ

For ZZ = 5 To 47 Step 7
    Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan").Range("D12:D18").Copy Range(Cells(ZZ, 5 + YY), Cells(ZZ + 6, 5 + YY))
    YY = YY + 1
Next ZZ

For ZZ = 12 To 26 Step 7
    Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan").Range("D12:D18").Copy Range(Cells(ZZ, 5 + YY), Cells(ZZ + 6, 5 + YY))
    YY = YY + 1
Next ZZ
```

I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Revising the code provided by Teamothy did the trick:

```
Sub CopyAndPaste()

Dim i As Long
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan").Range("D12:D18")

With Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan")

For i = 5 To 19
    If i <= 9 Then
    myRange.Copy .Range(.Cells(19 + 7 * (i - 5), i), .Cells(19 + 6 + 7 * (i - 5), i))
    ElseIf i > 9 And i < 17 Then
    myRange.Copy .Range(.Cells(5 + (7 * (i - 5)) - 35, i), .Cells(5 + 6 + (7 * (i - 5)) - 35, i))
    ElseIf i >= 17 Then
    myRange.Copy .Range(.Cells(5 + (7 * (i - 5)) - 84, i), .Cells(5 + 6 + (7 * (i - 5)) - 84, i))
    End If
Next

End With
```